# Delete records where timestamp is older than 5 minutes

Tags: mysql

I have a table called **filesUploaded**, with a column called **dataTimer** of type `varchar`.

When I record a new value in my table, I use the following command to enter the current date in timestamp format:

```
strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));//Example: 145879957
```

To delete records that have more than 5 minutes in my table I use this syntax:

```
DELETE FROM filesUploaded WHERE dataTimer < (NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
```

But it is not working, what might be happening?

Comment: Store your value as a date type not as varchar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue is your storing it in the format of varchar .

you need to convert it to date format and the you can delete

```
DELETE FROM filesUploaded WHERE STR_TO_DATE(dataTimer,%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S) < (NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
```